# Using more than two ranges in a VBA For loop

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to use a For loop to do stuff in three separate columns in Excel.

```
Sub dostuff()
  Dim lRw As Long, C As Range

  ' Get number of active rows by finding last row index.
  lRw = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For Each C In Range("B1:B" & lRw, "H1:H" & lRw)
  ' stuff happens
  Next
End Sub
```

This works fine when I only specify only one or two column ranges as above, but when I try adding in a third, it fails:

```
For Each C In Range("B1:B" & lRw, "H1:H" & lRw, "M1:M" & lRw)
```

Is there any way to iterate through three columns (or more) instead of just two?

Comment: `For Each C In Range("B1:B" & lRw & ",H1:H" & lRw & ",M1:M" & lRw)`

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried playing around with syntax like that, but unfortunately it doesn't work for any columns aside from the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a Union to combine your ranges before you do your loop

```
Dim loopRange as Range
Set loopRange = Union(Range("B1:B" & lRw),Range("H1:H" & lRw),Range("M1:M" & lRw))
For Each C In loopRange
    'stuff
Next C
```

Comment: Dean, just as with Tim's suggestion above, it only works for the first column. The remaining two columns are ignored.

Comment: What does it do for the other two columns? I tested this code on some sample ranges before I posted it.

Comment: Nevermind, I placed Set loopRange in the wrong place in my code. Works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub Tester()
Dim c As Range, lRw As Long

    lRw = 5
    For Each c In Range("B1:B" & lRw & ",H1:H" & lRw & ",M1:M" & lRw).Cells
        Debug.Print c.Address(False, False)
    Next c

End Sub
```